La funcion row_spec me genera una linea vacia
Estoy trabajando un pdf en Rstudio con markdown usando xelatex, con la nueva version de tinytex, la funcion row_spec crea una linea adicional luego de pedirle la linea horizontal en la fila.
Al crear el documento con la anterior version no tenia problemas
tabla <- data.frame(Suceso=c("H","M","Total"),
                Rosa=c(0.3,0.2,0.5),Azul=c(0.18,0.12,0.3),Verde=c(0.12,0.08,0.2), Total=c(0.6,0.4,1),check.names = F)

kable(tabla,align=c("l","c","c"),escape=F,booktabs=T,linesep="",digits = 2)%>%


kable_styling(bootstrap_options=c("striped","borderer","condensed"), 
            latex_options = "HOLD_position",full_width = F,font_size = 10)%>%
  column_spec(c(1,4),border_right = T)%>%
row_spec(2, hline_after = TRUE)



Revisaste el .tex que genera R Markdown? Si es tema de formato, podrías redefinir el estilo en el preámbulo

No conozco mucho por lo que no sabria que buscar en el .tex y como solucionarlo en el preambulo
